# deploy a java/mysql application

Tags: java

I created a java swing application using a MySQL database.
So I want to create an installer for the application so as it could be installed and runned on every pc having JRE installed.

After some researches, I found a way to achieve this using Launch4j and Inno Setup Compiler after generating the jar file.

The problem is that I don't know how to integrate the mysql database so as the application can be seen as a whole.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is more a comment that anything, but I need the extra space/formatting:

A MySQL install is not something I would do automatically for a user because:

a) You are creating services that the user may not know how to manage. You are installing a program that will open ports, that may need security updates, etc. If your final user has no IT background to properly manage that, it is clearly a security issue.

b) Maybe the user prefers another configuration. OTOH, if the user knows what he is doing, maybe he already has a MySQL install. He may prefer just to run your DB inside the MySQL that is already installed, because it is properly configured (including backups), it is in redundant hardware, whatever.

If you need a small, embedded database with your product, switch to Derby or Hypersonic.

If your product requires a full MySQL install, just provide (and document) a way for an IT operator do the installation by itself (give the SQL scripts to create and populate the database together with the code, specify how to configure the DB parameters in your application).